# How to remove default red bubble pin image in annotation

Tags: ios, swift, annotations, maps, mapkit

I have a lot of annotations which are displayed on map. Here is how it looks: [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ysmS.jpg)

Here is the code, which I'm using:

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {
    
        if annotation is UserPin {
            let pin = mapView.view(for: annotation) as? UserAnnotationView ?? UserAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: nil)
            pin.image = planeImg
            return pin

        } else {
            if annotation is AirplanePin {
                let reuseId = "planePin"

                    var anView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationView(withIdentifier: reuseId)
                    if anView == nil {
                        anView = AirplaneItemAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: reuseId)
                    }
                    else {
                        anView?.annotation = annotation
                    }
                
                let cpa = annotation as! AirplanePin
                    let icon : UIImageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 32, height: 32))
                icon.image = cpa.image
                    icon.layer.zPosition = 1
        
                    anView?.addSubview(icon)
                    anView?.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y:0, width:32, height:32)
                    anView?.canShowCallout = true
                    return anView
                
            }

        }
        return nil
    }
```

Annotation View Class:

```
import UIKit
import MapKit

class AirplaneItemAnnotationView: MKMarkerAnnotationView {
    private var imageView: UIImageView!

    override init(annotation: MKAnnotation?, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)



    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    
}
```

So, the main question is, how to remove this red bubbles and left only the planes icons?

Comment: Could you add an image of the red bubbles? Apart from this, MKMarkerAnnotationView has a glyphImage. You might try it instead of adding a subview https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mapkit/mkmarkerannotationview/2873823-glyphimage

Comment: I'm settings glyphImage to nil and it still appearing